# How to create a folder in the media manager upon installing a module

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Hey I am making my first module in Joomla!.

I want to create a new folder in Joomla!'s media manager when someone installs my module. I have been duck-duck-go-ing around and found some information. But I just can't get it to work. Probably because the information might be for older Joomla! versions. Or I might've implemented it wrong.

Anyway I came up with the following:

**mod_mymodule.xml**

```
<extension type="module" version="3.8.1" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <files>
        <scriptfile>install.componentname.php</scriptfile> 
    </files>
</extension>
```

**install.createmap.php**

```
<?php 
$destination = JPATH_SITE."/images/mynewmap";
JFolder::create($destination);
?>
```

Can anyone explain me how to add a folder to the media manager (root/images) on installing a module in Joomla 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a script.php file which executes your install tasks:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file

Here is the example content the script.php:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class mod_helloWorldInstallerScript
{
    function install($parent) 
    {
        echo '<p>The module has been installed</p>';
    }

    function uninstall($parent) 
    {
        echo '<p>The module has been uninstalled</p>';
    }

    function update($parent) 
    {
        echo '<p>The module has been updated to version' . $parent->get('manifest')->version . '</p>';
    }

    function preflight($type, $parent) 
    {
        echo '<p>Anything here happens before the installation/update/uninstallation of the module</p>';
    }

    function postflight($type, $parent) 
    {
        echo '<p>Anything here happens after the installation/update/uninstallation of the module</p>';
    }
}
```

It contains a class with some methods so you can create the necessary folder structure. You want to extend the postflight method.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why I should create the new folder in the postflight method and not the install method?

Comment: Because then everything was successful and you can do the final install steps. But in the end, this is up to you.

Comment: Alright. I will add it to the install method then, since I only want to add that folder on installation. I assume postflight will run the code after updates and uninstallations too, which I don t want. Thx for the reply.

Comment: You never know what people doing. So every update would fix the missing folder.